# Como mover las celdas a una posición con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito colocar en cada celda un enlace que al pincharlo el `<tr>` pinchado descienda un nivel.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con el DOM en javascript?, porque no lo entiendo, yo lo tengo así pero esta mal, estoy perdido la verdad.

```js
function ordenCeldas() {
  let tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let ultimo = tr[i].lastChild;
    console.log((tr[i] = tr[i].nextElementSibling));
    table.appendChild(tr[i].nextElementSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaPrincipal">
  <tbody id="tabla">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="mover(1)">UNO</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="mover(2)">DOS</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="mover(3)">TRES</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: En tu `onclick` llamas una función llamada `mover` pero no está definda. Y aunque fuera `ordenarCeldas` esa función no acepta parametros y le estás pasando uno

Answer (score 0):

Te paso una solucion, los eventos onclick los ejecuto dentro del archivo Javascript porque el problema de ponerlos en las etiquetas es que no puedo referirme a la etiqueta que hizo el click dentro de la funcion

```
<body>
    <table id="tablaPrincipal">
        <tbody id="tabla">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#">UNO</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#">DOS</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#">TRES</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#">CUATRO</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#">CINCO</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

ahora el JS:

```
const tabla = document.getElementById("tabla"); 

tabla.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((element)=>{
  element.addEventListener("click",()=>{ // agregamos el evento click a cada celda, y al hacerlo se ejecuta la funcion, pasando por parametros el nodo que activa el evento
    descend(element)
  })
})

function descend(node){ 
  if(node.nextElementSibling!==null){ // si el elemento tiene nodo siguiente:
    let next = node.nextElementSibling; // guardamos temporalmente el elemento siguiente
    tabla.removeChild(node.nextElementSibling) // eliminamos ese siguiente
    tabla.insertBefore(next,node) // insertamos antes del nodo que activa el evento el nodo guardado temporalmente
  }
}
```

Espero que te sirva